# XSD validation clarification for Amazon MWS product feed

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, xsd, amazon-mws

I am looking for some clarification regarding how to read the XSD that Amazon uses to validate their XML product feed.

This is the [XSD](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/amzn-envelope.xsd) used (and the inner [Product](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/Product.xsd) one) and these are the [docs](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl._V353515335_.pdf).

When I submit a basic product feed without a description or BulletPoint feed I get this error:

> A value was not provided for "bullet_point1". Please provide a value for "bullet_point1". This information appears on the product detail page and helps customers evaluate products.
>
> A value was not provided for "product_description". Please provide a value for "product_description". This information appears on the product detail page and helps customers evaluate products.

Here are the relevant XSD sections:

```
<xsd:element name="Description" minOccurs="0">
  <xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:normalizedString">
      <xsd:maxLength value="2000"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="BulletPoint" type="LongStringNotNull" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="5"/>
```

My understanding is that `minOccurs="0"` means its not required yet it clearly is. I have looked through a few other inner XSD (such as [Base](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/Base.xsd)) for these fields in case they were overridden but did not see anything.

Is this the wrong XSD? Am I reading this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `minOccurs="0"` means optional, however...

In general, applications often have additional requirements beyond those specified in the XSD of its XML input.  When parameters are required only in certain circumstances, an XSD will list them as optional in the general case but then check them out-of-band wrt the XSD.  (XSD 1.1 provides some additional expressiveness via `xs:assertion` for conditionally requiring elements/attributes, but it's not widely adopted yet.)

Note that `bullet_point1` does not appear in any of the XSDs or documentation you've linked to your question.  If `bullet_point1` is derived from `BulletPoint` in the XSD, then it clearly is a downstream application that's making the additional requirement and issuing the error when it's unmet.

Comment: Yes - I suspect it is some other downstream. Amazon accepts xls files which do contain the bullet_point1-5. I was hoping to make informed validation decisions but I guess its going to be a try and tell thing.

Answer (score 2):

I asked to the amazon developers this question and they answered to me:

> xsd of categories are not correctly updated so some elements would be
>   required but not reflected in the .xsd document thaty's the problem.